# How can I make it easier to use the mouse to expand column widths?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, gui, cursor

It seems like anytime I want to click between columns to expand them I end up miss clicking and dragging the column instead of expanding it. I've been told by an old friend that this is because the hotspot on the mouse cursor is too small. This makes sense to me because I find it extremely difficult to click on that one or two wide pixel line that separates columns. This happens no matter what program I'm using. Windows Explorer, Excel, SharePoint, Word. Is there an easier way to expand/contract the columns? Is there a way to increase the size of my hotspot on the mouse cursor? I've looked online and everything seems to point to changing the hotspot within a custom C# program.

Comment: I'd suggest starting somewhere more simplistic - make sure your mouse is on a good surface for detecting input. You also may want to turn your mouse sensitivity down to increase your movement accuracy.

Comment: @GeoffDawdy Click to highlight the entire column you want to expand in Excel and then press `Alt` + `H`, `O`, `I` where `I` as in `eye`....which are the hot keys for `Format` | `AutoFit Colum Width`... I'll be happy to add as an answer if this works for your need. You can also do a `Ctrl` + `A` and then press the hot key combo to do this for all columns